# what is the meaning of injecting a dll into a proccess and what is api hooking

Tags: windows

what is the meaning of injecting a dll into a proccess and what is api hooking***

---

- List item

---

Answer (score 0):

API hooking is the technique used to tap into function calls from a third-party-program into the Windows API.

There are two different techniques:

- one is the standard notifications you can get by registering API-Hooks with Windows; Windows then informs your program voluntarily
- the other is to rewrite the calls the third-party-software makes into the Windows-API with jumps into YOUR program. This is more difficult (see MSDN for WriteProcssMemory()) but gives you the power to modify what the third-party-software does instead of just logging it.

You can find information on both of them in: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hooksys.aspx